# Combine two cypher queries into single query and single result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created the query to get list of people in country & some avg calculation:

```
Match (people:People)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(address:Address), (people)-[:SOME]->(calc)
RETURN address.country as name, count(*) as count, avg(calc.value) as value
```

Which returns corect values for instance:

```
name, count, value
PL  , 5    , 10
UK  , 3    , 20
US  , 6    , 30
DE  , 3    , 40
```

What I'm trying to achive is also get the countries of people that they know, so expected result should look e.g. like this:

```
name, count, value, knowsAlso
PL  , 5    , 10   , UK,US
UK  , 3    , 20   , DE
US  , 6    , 30   , 
DE  , 3    , 40   ,
```

I created a separate query to get that information by passing the $country:

```
Match (firstPerson:Person)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(firstAddress:Address),
      (firstPerson:Person)-[:FRIEND_WITH]->(secondPerson:Person),
      (secondPerson:Person)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(secondAddress:Address)
WHERE firstAddress.country = $country
AND firstAddress.country <> secondAddress.country
RETURN DISTINCT secondAddress.country
```

but in this scenario I need to invoke it for each record on the result set from first query which doesn't seem to be effective. Is there a way to invoke my second query directly on the result set of the previous query? Or ideally, make these two queries as a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you:

```
MATCH (calc)<-[:SOME]-(p:People)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(a1:Address)
WITH a1.country AS name,
     COUNT(*) AS count,
     AVG(calc.value) AS value,
     COLLECT(DISTINCT p) AS pList
UNWIND pList AS p1
OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[:FRIEND_WITH]->(:Person)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(a2:Address)
WHERE name <> a2.country
RETURN name, count, value, COLLECT(DISTINCT a2.country) AS knowsAlso
```

Comment: Hey @cybersam. I want to return people with some calculations located in the address (that's main priority) and additionally return a new column which is the location of a friend if he has them. While I tested your solution it seemed that it returns only persons that meet all conditions (has calculations, located in, and has friends located in) ignoring people which doesn't have friends.

Comment: What was missing was the word OPTIONAL before the second match, please edit your answer by passing OPTIONAL before the second MATCH :) Anyway accepted,thanks!